# 95% confidence interval on demand

Tags: probability, statistics

A company selling oil operates a storage tank to serve 10 customer locations. The monthly oil demand at each customer location is normally distributed with mean 50 million gallons and standard deviation 15 million gallons. The demands at different customer locations are independent of each other. What is the minimum amount of oil needed in the storage tank to cover all customer demand 95% of the time?

My question is: Is this equivalent to finding the 95% confidence interval for demand for each location and then multiplying that by 10? If it is, then $Z = (X-50)/15$ and the value of Z that corresponds to 95% CI is 1.65, meaning X = 74.75 and total oil needed is 747.5 million gallons.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, though you can never tell what the test setter intended to mean.  I read this as a single storage tank refilled once a month.

You might consider the total of demand, and the standard deviation of this total, and so how much is needed to have a 95% confidence of meeting total demand that month.  If you recalculate on this basis, you should get a result closer to the mean value of $500$.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding you but when I did it again, it seems like I get the same answer. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @hello888: Mr Renard has done half the work for you.  Even if one customer location might be above its 95% point, other are likely to be below, offsetting the amount needed from the tank.  So the tank can be smaller than you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Henry. Remember that when adding normal distributions, the variance (and not the standard deviation) adds linearly. To be more clear, the mean of 10 normal distribution is:

$\mu_{Tot} = 10 * \mu = 10 * 50$

but the standard deviation of 10 normal distribution is:

$\sigma_{Tot} = \sqrt{10 * \sigma^2} = \sqrt{10} * 15$

then you can recompute your Z significance with $\mu_{Tot}$ and $\sigma_{Tot}$.